# Copying files from svn repository

Tags: linux, svn, centos

I wanna copy files and folders from my svn repository on server, but I dont want to install svn client, can I do it without svn client?

PS server - linux (CentOS 5.5), svnadmin version 1.4.2 (r22196)compiled Aug 10 2009, 17:54:46.

UPD: files are already exported to server: I want to import files from svn repository to directory, where web-server runs. For example: svn repository located at /var/svn/repos, I wanna dump repository to /var/www, but in /var/svn/repos no files I needed.

PSS sorry for my bad english =\

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Subversion repository isn't in a readable format that you can peruse like you could with CVS. To read the files in the repository you need someone with a client somewhere.

If your Subversion repository uses Apache httpd for its server, you can use `wget` or `curl` to pull off the last revision on a specific directory since *as an added bonus*, the Subversion Apache httpd modules allow you to see the latest version.

```
$ wget http://svn/repos/foo/trunk/myfile.java
```

The other option is to use a Subversion repository browser like (ViewVC)[http://www.viewvc.org/] or [Sventon](http://www.sventon.org/). These will allow you to browse the entire repository (including older revisions) without having to install the Subversion client on the local machine. I like Sventon because it doesn't have to run from the Subversion repository server.

If you're on Centos 5.5, you should already have the Subversion command line client installed on your system. In that case, if you don't want the `.svn` directories, use the `svn export` command instead of `svn checkout`.

Or, setup your web server to ignore the `.svn` directories. That way, you can do an `svn update` and update the files on your web server without having to redownload everything.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you have physical access to the server you could use the Subversion client on that box to export files/folders and then copy them from the server to the client machine.  If you're trying to do this purely from the client, the only way I can think of would be to manually download the file(s) from the web client but this will only work if you're using Apache as your Subversion server.

Comment: Yes, my Subversion server is Apache, but if have not physical access to the server.

Comment: You can download your files manually via the built-in web interface then.  If you serve a repository from http://yourhostname_or_ip/repos/svn/test_repo, you should be able to put that url into a web browser and view/download files that way.

Answer (score 2):

Unless the server has an HTTP interface (is the repository URL prefixed with `http://`? Just open it up in a web browser), no.

It might be simplest to export the files you want on the server (`svn export file://repo/path/to/directory`), then copy them to the client using http or scp or something.

Comment: Nope, files are already exported to server: I want to import files from svn repository to directory, where web-server runs.